# FilePathResult works for ActionLink but doesn't work from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm not sure why this occurring, but when I call my action from a "ActionLink" it works properly, but when I call it from javascript it doesn't.  Both methods get to the "ExportFile" method, but only the "ActionLink" shows the file at the bottom of the browser for Chrome when downloading a file, but it doesn't for the javascript call.  Below is my action method and below that is my View.  Why will one work but not the other?

```
public FilePathResult ExportFile()
{
    string path = @"c:\1\text.xxx";
    bool ex = System.IO.File.Exists(path);
    return File( path,"application/text", "text.xxx");
}
```

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <input type="button" id="Export" value="Export" />

  <%=Html.ActionLink("export", "ExportFile") %>

  <div id="ExportProgress"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Export").bind("click", ExportHandler);
                //alert("bind");
            });

            function ExportHandler() {
                $.get("/DataExport/ExportFile", function () { }, 'html');
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Figured it out.  Just had to set the location in the javascript.

Comment: Post that as an answer.